# Use column names for a new object

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 5 columns: two are date-time and the remaining three contain data. I would like, using a loop or defying a function, to create 3 new data frames using the names of the columns containing the data.
Here is an example of the column I have:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih7TC.png)

So for example I'd like to create new object, each called `11.Q.29` (or if there is a way to combine this with a text, that suggestion is also welcomed!), with column Date and the actual Q, so that I can apply the hydrostats package. The question is whether there is a way to tell R to do it, or I have to do it manually for each column?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a similar Dataframe:

```
testing <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100, 60, replace=TRUE), ncol=6))
names(testing) = c("date", "time", "10.Q.29", "10.Q.30", "10.Q.36", "10.Q.63")
```

As you said, you want to create a dataframe for specific columns. In this case, the goal is from the third to the sixth one.

One approach would be to extract just the columns you want:

```
posData = testing[,c(3:ncol(testing))]
```

Define the name for each new dataframes. Notice that I added a prefix:

```
newDfName = paste("newDf", names(posData), sep="_")
```

Then, extract the information and create a dataframe for each column by using
`assign`:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(posData))
{
    tmpDf = as.data.frame(posData[,i])
    assign(newDfName[i], tmpDf)
}
```

You can check the results by using `ls()`:

```
> ls()
[1] "i"             "newDf_10.Q.29" "newDf_10.Q.30" "newDf_10.Q.36" "newDf_10.Q.63" "newDfName"    
[7] "posData"       "testing"       "tmpDf"        
>
```